# Dynamic GeoServer SLD styling template to use on Multiple Polygon shapefiles

Tags: geoserver, sld

I'm trying to create 1 SLD template for the Geoserver application on any point shapefile I upload.
For example, I want a styling that will automatically color the attributes for the selected layer. If layer 1 has 5 unique records the styling should pull through this.
[image]

And if I upload a different point shapefile(another layer) and select the same SLD template with more unique attributes it should automatically pull it through.

[image]

Please is this possible??

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible, the rules to drive coloring need to be set statically once.
It may be possible to create a new function associating a random color to unique values of a field, but it would still be problematic for tiling (would end up generating different colors for the same feature... generating the color from a hash of the class value would be another option, but it would risk generating the same color, or a color that's too similar, for two different classes).

As a better alternative, install the [SLD REST service](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/sldservice/index.html) extension and call it to generate a classified style right after uploading a new shapefile.